# Query to compare first two words of a column in a table and match it to another column in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as follows

```
Company       Country
---------------------
abc 123 abc    USA
def 456 def    USA
ghi 789 ghi    USA

Company             State
------------------------
abc 123               TX
def 234 def def       NY
ghi 789               AZ
```

I need to query Company from table 1 and compare the first two words with Company in tabl2 and print output if it matches.
I have successfully managed to get the first two words from the table 1 using the code

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (
          tbSurvey.company,
          0,
          CHARINDEX (' ',
                     tbSurvey.company,
                     CHARINDEX (' ', tbSurvey.company, 0) + 1))
  FROM tbSurvey;
```

I am unable to match the Column to the company column in table 2. I am trying to use the code,

```
SELECT endcustomername, endcustomercode, country
  FROM tbLicense
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT company, endcustomername, endcustomercode
             FROM tbSurvey, tblicense
            WHERE     tbSurvey.company < tbLicense.endcustomername
                  AND tbSurvey.company <> ' '
                  AND tbLicense.endcustomercode LIKE
                           SUBSTRING (
                              tbSurvey.company,
                              0,
                              CHARINDEX (
                                 ' ',
                                 tbSurvey.company,
                                 CHARINDEX (' ', tbSurvey.company, 0) + 1))
                         + '%');
```

But I am not getting the desired output. Please help.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

well it's not very concise and readable, but I think it do the job you need

```
with cte_survey as (
    select
        t.*,
        case when s.i > 0 then left(t.company, s.i - 1) else t.company end as k
    from tbSurvey as t
        outer apply (select charindex(' ', t.company) as i) as f
        outer apply (select case when f.i > 0 then charindex(' ', t.company, f.i + 1) else len(company) end as i) as s
)
select
    s.company as sur_compant, l.company as lic_company, s.country, l.[state] as [state]
from cte_survey as s
    inner join tblicense as l on l.company = s.k
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8750/32)

If you want to compare both columns by first 2 words:

```
with cte_survey as (
    select
        t.*,
        case when s.i > 0 then left(t.company, s.i - 1) else t.company end as k
    from tbSurvey as t
        outer apply (select charindex(' ', t.company) as i) as f
        outer apply (select case when f.i > 0 then charindex(' ', t.company, f.i + 1) else len(company) end as i) as s
),
cte_license as (
    select
        t.*,
        case when s.i > 0 then left(t.company, s.i - 1) else t.company end as k
    from tblicense as t
        outer apply (select charindex(' ', t.company) as i) as f
        outer apply (select case when f.i > 0 then charindex(' ', t.company, f.i + 1) else len(company) end as i) as s
)  
select
    s.company as sur_compant, l.company as lic_company, s.country, l.[state] as [state]
from cte_survey as s
    inner join cte_license as l on l.k = s.k
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8750/31)

Comment: This an SQL server only solution. How do you know OP is even using that?